# Using EmguCV along with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

EmguCV is a wrapper library for OpenCV in C#.

So I'm developing a web app for my Database course which is a police database system for storing criminal records using Asp.Net MVC, Entity Framework, and SQL Server. Here I am planning to implement facial recognition by applying Open CV's eigenfaces algorithm. So the problem here is that I've looked upon some threads here on StackOverflow regarding this but the answers are too vague. The problem is that OpenCV contains all files which can't be hosted on a web server and of course can't be executed there. If I were to deploy this project in a production environment, what approach would I follow?

One suggestion on a thread was that to make a console application as a separate project which only processes the image using EmguCV and another project within the same solution which will be an MVC application. The web app will pass the image to the desktop application and it will process it further. But again the problem here is that I can't deploy both the console application and a desktop application on the same server.

What approach would I follow?

Comment: You can launch executable from asp.net page. Your console application writes images to disk, and your web application reads from disk after. What do you think?

Comment: That's what I said but I think it would consume a lot of time knowing that it must run both the console app and the web app, but I'll answer this once I've deployed it.